# ERROR:failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1 while deploying nextjs on railway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, railway

---

> [stage-0  8/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8a557944-4c41-4e06-8de9-06bfcc5e8aaf-next/cache,target=/app/.next/cache --mount=type=cache,id=s/8a557944-4c41-4e06-8de9-06bfcc5e8aaf-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build:

17.62

17.62 Import trace for requested module:

17.62 ./node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/react/index.mjs

17.62 ./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/esm/hooks/useOrganization.js

17.62 ./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/esm/hooks/index.js

17.62 ./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/esm/index.js

17.62 ./app/(auth)/sign-up/[[...sign-up]]/page.jsx

17.62

17.62

17.62 > Build failed because of webpack errors

---

Dockerfile:24

---

22 |     # build phase

23 |     COPY . /app/.

24 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8a557944-4c41-4e06-8de9-06bfcc5e8aaf-next/cache,target=/app/.next/cache --mount=type=cache,id=s/8a557944-4c41-4e06-8de9-06bfcc5e8aaf-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run build

25 |

26 |

---

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Error: Docker build failed

i'm facing this error deploying in railway.app

Answer (score 0):

show all log, in my case it was because in an import of an interface it was with uppercase and it was lowercase